# End an if statement without moving to next lines

Tags: python, if-statement

So I'm trying to make a little fun code to test my skills, and I'm trying to get the first if statement to continue to the next if statement, that is if they answer yes. If they answer anything other than yes, the code ends. How do I change it so the code actually ends if they answer incorrectly?

```
print('Would you like to begin?')

answer = input()

if answer == 'yes':
    print('What is your name?')
    #continue to the next portion when if statement is true
else:
    print('ok')
   #break the code when else statement is true
name = input()

if name == 'Test':
    print('Congratulations! You won!')
else:
    print('Good try. The answer was Test.')
```

Comment: It sounds like all the flow should be part of the true block of the if statement

Comment: If you don't otherwise exit the code, the body of if statement continues on its own

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `#break the code when else statement is true` with `import sys; sys.exit(0)`.

If they answer `'yes'`, it will simply continue to `name = input()`.

Comment: Awesome, this worked for me! I'm very beginner so this helps a lot